# To learn on its own

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word which captures when something learns/progresses on its own?  For example if an animal is able to learn a complicated task on its own, what would be a (1-word) name for that process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a noun '*Autodidact*'.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/autodidact :

***autodidact***

: a self-taught person

// was an autodidact
who read voraciously

According to Macmillan Dictionary
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/autodidact?q=Autodidact+ :

***AUTODIDACT***

a person who has taught themselves rather than
receiving formal 
education

'Benjamin Franklin was a celebrated 
American statesman,
 and an autodidact as well'.

According to Wikipedia 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidacticism :

'an autodidact is an individual who chooses the subject they will study, their studying material, and the studying rhythm and time.'